Fresnel - Unwanted Glow on Face Edges / Corners
When using the Fresnel shading node in Blender, it is affecting faces turned at angles away from the camera as expected, but I am also seeing unwanted areas, that are not faces, but rather edges of faces, or the corners between faces being lit by the Fresnel node.
This file is using Cycles for rendering and in the 3D Viewport. I’m not sure that it matters, but the mesh is a very low poly. Each face in the picture is indeed only a single face.

At the top of this image is the 3D Viewport and at the bottom is the Shader Editor. Notice the lit edges in the red circled area.
Question 1.
Is there a way to get rid of this?
Question 2.
Is there any relationship between the Fresnel node and ambient occlusion?
Attached is the *.blend file.


Are you sure this is coming from the Fresnel node ? You are mixing with a material we don't see. Uploading your file to https://blend-exchange.com/ would be great.

Hello and welcome. Please don't crop out essential information from your screenshots, this hides away any details that could possibly hint at what your issue is. As it stands a partial screenshot of the subject without context or further information makes it impossible to diagnose the issue. Please edit your post and replace your images with full uncropped screenshots showing the user interface, properties, and any relevant parameters that might help us solve the issue.

What makes you think that comes from the fresnel node? I can see non shader node connected to a shader socket in your node tree, which is non standard and a sure way to get unexpected results

@Lutzi I made this file specifically to demonstrate this, so there aren't any complicating factors that I'm aware of. I've uploaded the Blender file. Here's the link:


@Staq I took a look, no idea why you get this result. Sidenote, plugging a Color as a Shader will behave as an Emission shader with strength 1. You can do that but explicit nodes are always better. Hope someone can give some insight on this behavior.

@DuarteFarrajotaRamos Thanks to you and Lutzi for pointing out the issues with plugging colour or non shader nodes into shader sockets. I'm new to shaders in general, so could you tell me specifically which thing I plugged into an incorrect socket? And then, is there another way to achieve the same thing, where I simply want to apply the Fresnel effect to an object with a single coloured surface?

The principled BSDF shader already has Fresnel built into it. If you want to use Fresnel to affect colors you should feed it into a Color Mix node
